# Combine columns using formattable in R

Tags: r, formattable

I am trying to use formattable on for better visualization of the table. What I want to do is combine columns name and difference to be shown together under one column. I have formatted the column difference. How do I combine here to show them as one column:

```
library(readr)
library(formattable)

df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:10,
  name = c("Bob", "Ashley", "James", "David", "Jenny", 
           "Hans", "Leo", "John", "Emily", "Lee"), 
  test1_score = c(8.9, 9.5, 9.6, 8.9, 9.1, 9.3, 9.3, 9.9, 8.5, 8.6),
  test2_score = c(9.1, 9.1, 9.2, 9.1, 8.9, 8.5, 9.2, 9.3, 9.1, 8.8),
 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

formattable(
  df %>%
    mutate("difference" = df$test1_score - df$test2_score),
  list(difference = formatter(
    "span",
    style = x ~ style(color = ifelse(x >= 0, "green", "red")),
    x ~ icontext(ifelse(x >= 0, "arrow-up", "arrow-down"), round(x, 2))
  )) 
)
```

[image]

Comment: Why have you given green up arrow for negative numbers?

Comment: I just modified it

Comment: Can you explain what is that you are looking as a output.

Comment: A new column which would be (Name + difference) including the icon and style